# Google scholar blocks python scrapy with Captcha

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm debugging a short script to get the citation counts and abstracts from a list of papers.  While debugging I encountered a Captcha block.  However, I was only executing the script every 4-5 minutes at the most frequently.  Here's a minimal working example that reproduces my problem:

```
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
import re

class ResArt_Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "restart_spider"

    def start_requests(self):
        url_start = "https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=GHG+emission+pathways+until+2300+for+the+1.5%C2%B0C+temperature+rise+target+and+the+mitigation+costs+achieving+the+pathways&btnG="
        yield scrapy.Request(url = url_start, callback = self.parse_metrics)

    def parse_metrics(self, response):
        # scrape to extract abstract and citations
        citation_block = response.css('body > div#gs_top > div#gs_bdy ::text').extract()
        print(citation_block)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    getArt = CrawlerProcess()
    getArt.crawl(ResArt_Spider)
    getArt.start()
```

For a bit of time I was able get a list back and search the list for the citation and the abstract.  I did that to minimize the requests on google scholar even though I was only debugging and making requests every 4-5 minutes.  So I only ever got back 1 item per session.

Here is a truncated version of the response to the scrapy call:

```
2020-11-02 14:13:02 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.5.0 started (bot: scrapybot)
2020-11-02 14:13:02 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: ... Python 3.6.2 |Anaconda ...
2020-11-02 14:13:02 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings: {}
2020-11-02 14:13:02 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
...
2020-11-02 14:13:02 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
...
2020-11-02 14:13:02 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
...
2020-11-02 14:13:02 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2020-11-02 14:13:02 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2020-11-02 14:13:02 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2020-11-02 14:13:02 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2020-11-02 14:13:03 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://scholar.google.com/scholar?
hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=GHG+emission+pathways+until+2300+for+the+1.5%C2%B0C+temperature+rise+target+and+
the+mitigation+costs+achieving+the+pathways&btnG=> (referer: None)
['#gs_captcha_ccl{max-width:680px;margin:21px 0;}.gs_el_sm #gs_captcha_ccl{margin:13px 0;}
#gs_captcha_ccl h1{font-size:16px;line-height:24px;font-weight:normal;padding:0 0 16px 0;}',
'function gs_captcha_cb(){grecaptcha.render("gs_captcha_c",
{"sitekey":"6LfFDwUTAAAAAIyC8IeC3aGLqVpvrB6ZpkfmAibj","callback":function()
{document.getElementById("gs_captcha_f").submit()}});};', "Please show you're not a robot", 
"Sorry, we can't verify that you're not a robot when JavaScript is turned off.", 'Please ', 
'enable JavaScript', ' in your browser and reload this page.']
2020-11-02 14:13:03 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2020-11-02 14:13:03 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
...
```

I line-wrapped the `[scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200)` and the returned list so they're both easier to read.

**Questions:**

- will getting a different `site-key` solve this problem?  If so, how do I go about getting one?
- are their any methods in scrapy, or plug-ins for scrapy, that could solve this? I couldn't find any that specifically mentioning being able to solve this problem.
- any other suggestions besides contacting google.  I contacted google scholar help and am awaiting their response.

**Related (but not helpful) SO Q&A's:**

- [Avoiding Google Scholar block for crawling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14530019/avoiding-google-scholar-block-for-crawling). They got a warning violating Terms of Service.  I did not.  Plus they're using urllib, not scrapy.
- [Google scholar Captcha verification problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6180638/google-scholar-captcha-verification-problem).  9 and a half years ago the answer was: there's not a scholar.google API.  Any new developments since then?
- [Google CSE, Google Scholar search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37258515/google-cse-google-scholar-search) provides link to a google scholar parser, but it doesn't fetch the abstract, only the citation count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `Google Cache` along with a `referer`.

Also, note not to send more than 2 requests/sec. You may get blocked:

```
headers = {"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36" ,'referer':'https://www.google.com/'}
```

Comment: Thanks, does `headers` go in the script, or outside the script in a bash?

Answer (score -2):

Please follow the rules in the TOS.

From https://scholar.google.com/intl/en/scholar/help.html#export

> > I wrote a program to download lots of search results, but you blocked my computer from accessing Google Scholar. Can you raise the limit?
>
> Err, no, please respect our robots.txt when you access Google Scholar using automated software. As the wearers of crawler's shoes and webmaster's hat, we cannot recommend adherence to web standards highly enough.

The robots.txt file can be found at https://scholar.google.com/robots.txt and currently contains:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /search
Disallow: /index.html
Disallow: /scholar
Disallow: /citations?
Allow: /citations?user=
Disallow: /citations?*cstart=
Disallow: /citations?user=*%40
Disallow: /citations?user=*@
Allow: /citations?view_op=list_classic_articles
Allow: /citations?view_op=metrics_intro
Allow: /citations?view_op=new_profile
Allow: /citations?view_op=sitemap
Allow: /citations?view_op=top_venues

User-agent: Twitterbot
Disallow:

User-agent: facebookexternalhit
Disallow:
```

Comment: You didn't answer the question. Instead you threw a couple of red herrings: I made one request, not "download lots".  My requests were every 4-5 minutes: slower than a human.

Comment: In fact, your own post confirms my ability to do what I am trying to do.  Your post includes the phrase: "when you access Google Scholar using automated software."

Comment: So as not to confuse you, that's one **unique** request, made every 4-5 minutes while debugging.